# Send javascript file using nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have nodejs server and it sends javascript file to the client. But in client side this javascript file doesn't import libraries, that use. In the client side I load this libraries and then recieve file. Why this file does't find the libraries. Any ideas?
Project structure: [image]

Controller.js code:

```
$(document).attr("title", "Модерен всеки ден");
const mainContent = $('#main-content');
$('#h1').html('Онлайн магазин за аксесоари');

if (window.sessionStorage.length < 2) {
    $('#login').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#register').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#logout').addClass('hidden');
    $('#shopping-bag').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#username-label').addClass('hidden');
} else {
    $('#login').addClass('hidden');
    $('#register').addClass('hidden');
    $('#logout').removeClass('hidden').on('click', () => {window.sessionStorage.clear(); window.location.href = ''});
    $('#shopping-bag').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#username-label').html(`Здравей ${window.sessionStorage.getItem('firstName')}!`).removeClass('hidden');
}

Promise.all([
    loadTemplate('home'),
    data.getHotOffers()
]).then(([template, offers]) => {
    if (mainContent.children().length === 2) {
        $(mainContent).children().first().remove();
    }
    mainContent.prepend(template(JSON.parse(offers)));
}, err => console.log(err));
```

Node JS server code:

```
.....
app.get('/home-controller', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile('./controllers/homeController.js', { root: __dirname });
});
......
```

Main.js code:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
import Navigo from 'navigo';
import { load as loadTemplate } from 'templates';
import * as data from 'data';
import * as request from 'requester';

const router = new Navigo(null, true, '#!');
router.on({'/': request.get('/home-controller')
}).resolve();
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the same code or share it on github?

Comment: Can you provide code ? For what I understand, from back-end, You can't import entire libraries, only data to the client.

Comment: okey, i will post

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a .js file. You can send HTML that then includes a script tag that gets used immediately. Or that references an external script.

res.send('    js code here   ')
You didnt post enough code though, more code would help us help you.